# How to refactor multiple if statements into much cleaner code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple if statements in react js like this :

```
    if (props.match.params.location && props.match.params.search && props.match.params.subcategory) {
                return console.log('search with loc and subcategory ');
            }
            if (props.match.params.location && props.match.params.search) {
                return console.log('search with loc ');
            }
            if (props.match.params.search && props.match.params.subcategory) {
                return console.log('search with subcategory ');
            }
            if (props.match.params.search) {
                return console.log('search');
            }
            if (props.match.params.location) {
                return console.log('loc  ');
            }
            if (props.match.params.location && props.match.params.subcategory) {
                return console.log('loc sub ');
            }
            if (props.match.params.subcategory) {
                return console.log(' sub ');
            }
```

Whats the best way to refactor this code into much simpler and easier to read code ?

Comment: Honestly, it's not going to get a lot better than this. My recommendation for readability is to destructure your variables with `const {location, search, subcategory} = props.match.params;`. This will go a long way towards readability.

Comment: You can use any Router for this.Or `let {location,search,subcategory} = props.match.params` also,You don't need `return` just use `else if...`

Comment: I think you might have a bug: you're checking `if (location)` before `if (location && subcategory) {`, so the second will never be entered. Do you want to flip those around?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for mentioning and no I coded that way purposefully so if the first statement matches , the rest won't execute .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also extract the properties from the object first:

```
const { location, search, subcategory } = props.match.params;
if (location && search && subcategory) {
  return console.log('search with loc and subcategory ');
}
if (location && search) {
  return console.log('search with loc ');
}
if (search && subcategory) {
  return console.log('search with subcategory ');
}
if (search) {
  return console.log('search');
}
if (location) {
  return console.log('loc  ');
}
if (location && subcategory) {
  return console.log('loc sub ');
}
if (subcategory) {
  return console.log(' sub ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine a string based on the conditions:

```
let string = "";
if(condition1) 
    string += "search ";
if(condition2)
    string += "loc ";

return console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
if(props.match.params.search) {
  if(props.match.params.location) {
    if(props.match.params.subcategory) {
      return console.log('search with loc and subcategory ');
    }
    
    return console.log('search with loc ');
  }
  
  if(props.match.params.subcategory) {
    return console.log('search with subcategory ');
  }
 
  return console.log('search');
}    

if (props.match.params.location) {
  if(props.match.params.subcategory) {
    return console.log('loc sub ');
  }
  
  return console.log('loc  ');
}

if (props.match.params.subcategory) {
  return console.log(' sub ');
}
```